# Avoiding temporary files in zsh

Tags: command-line, zsh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shell programming, avoiding tempfiles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21602/shell-programming-avoiding-tempfiles)

Say I have the file `data.txt`, and the command `cmd`.

`cmd` takes one argument, a file. Or, you could use `stdin`.

Now, say `data.txt` is uppercase, but `cmd` only works if all data is lowercase.

Sure, you could do this

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < data.txt > lowercase_data.txt
cmd lowercase_data.txt
rm lowercase_data.txt
```

But, is there a way to integrate this?

Like, a wrapper around the original file, that applies a filter, then passes a reference to the temporary file; the command is executed; last, the temporary file is deleted?

I use zsh.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: @ReedKraft-Murphy: zsh

Comment: As a `bash` user I'm not itimately familiar with `zsh`, but it appears to support [process substitution](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_7.html): possibly `cmd =(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < data.txt)` would do it, but I'll let someone more `zsh` savvy followup.

Comment: @ReedKraft-Murphy: No, that seems to work! If bash has it, I think zsh does to :) If you convert your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Since the program accepts input via stdin, why not just a plain old pipe: `<data.txt tr ... | cmd`?

Comment: @Kevin: So, **that's** the syntax! I knew there was a way (that's why I mentioned it - also, because it is a very common case) but I just couldn't get it right. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`zsh` supports [process substitution](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_7.html), which should do what you're asking:

```
A command of the form =(...) is replaced with the name of a file containing its output.
```

So for your example, to avoid manually creating a temporary file to pass the output of `tr` into `cmd`, you could say

```
cmd =(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < data.txt)
```

For other shells, the equivalent would be:

- **`bash`**: `cmd <(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < data.txt)`
- **`ksh`**: `cmd <(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < data.txt)`
- **`rc`**: `cmd <{tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < data.txt}`

Note that `bash`, `ksh` and `rc` implement process substitution using named pipes, rather than temporary files as `zsh` uses, and require the `/dev/fd/` filesystem to be mounted

Comment: `zsh` also supports the same `<(...)` form used by `bash` and `ksh`. The `=(...)` is made available for situations where the command will try to do something (like seek backwards) to the argument that isn't possible with a pipe.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the way you do it. Except for the way you create your temp files (what if the script you're running is executed twice concurrently?).

You should use `mktemp` instead.

Comment: So there is no tool or well-known method to do this? You should use temporary files explicitly, only with `mktemp` to make it secure?

Comment: I don't get it. `mktemp` **is** the tool you're looking for. Your usage of temporary files is totally justified. I used to ask myself the same question. Take a look at the question I link to in the comments of your question.

Comment: The point is not how to avoid using temporary files but to integrate that dance: create file - run command - remove file -- so that the temporary files would not have to be bothered with explicitly.