# Is it possible to create a "file" that can be used by any process without actually saving the file on disk?

Tags: shell, files, io-redirection, arguments

Suppose I do a `grep` that gives me a lot of results. I want to use the output of grep and pass it to a command that takes a filename as it's first argument. For example -

```
myCommand filename.txt
```

I would like to do something like this -

```
grep "xyz" | myCommand
```

However, since myCommand doesn't read from stdin, this piping does not work. I don't want to create a temporary file on disk with the results of grep. Is it possible by any other means to create a "file", say in memory and let `myCommand` use that?

Comment: Possibly related. I asked a [similar question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21602/shell-programming-avoiding-tempfiles) here once. It's okay to create the temporary files. You'll find some good practice on how to do this in the answers linked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution is to use Bash's support for process substitution, like this:

```
myCommand <(grep "xyz" somefile)
```

This will connect the output of the `grep` command to a file descriptor and then pass `/dev/fd/NNN` (where `NNN` is the fd number) to your command as the input file (for example, your command might actually get run as `myCommand /dev/fd/63`). This solution *does not* create a temporary file.

You can also create a named pipe and use that to transfer data around:

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/myfifo
$ grep "xyz somefile > /tmp/myfifo &
$ myCommand /tmp/myfifo
```

But really, the first solution is simpler.

Stephane Chazelas comments:

> zsh also has myCommand =(grep xyz somefile) which uses a regular
>   temporary file (for cases where myCommand can't accept a pipe).

This is important because some commands expect to be able to perform random access on their input file, which won't work with a pipe.  Using this syntax you get the benefits of temporary files without needing to worry about cleaning them up yourself.

Comment: Note that although process substitution is great here, it's not supported by all shells or on all operating systems. The fifo approach should work just about everywhere.

Comment: myCommand <(grep "xyz" somefile) didn't work on Ubuntu for me. Now I'm trying the second approach.

Comment: @CodeBlue, note that the first solution does, as I indicated, require Bash.  If you're using a different shell there might be a different syntax (or there might not be an equivalent feature).

Comment: process substitution originated in ksh93 and is also available in zsh and bash. zsh also has `myCommand =(grep xyz somefile)` which uses a regular temporary file (for cases where myCommand can't accept a pipe).

Comment: Stephane: good to know, I've added this to the answer.

Comment: @larsks when I do echo $0 on my Ubuntu terminal, I get /bin/bash. So it is indeed using the bash shell, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Update: on Ubuntu, the first solution works for some commands but not for others.

Answer (score 2):

Most distros now include a RAM disk for this exact purpose. You can write files to it like normal, it's typically called `/dev/shm`. You can check if you have it like so:

```
$ mount |grep shm
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
```

If you have it you can write to it just like any other filesystem:

```
$ echo "hello world" > /dev/shm/somefile.txt
```

And see it using normal tools:

```
$ ls -l /dev/shm/
total 680
-r-------- 1 saml saml 67108904 Jul 22 20:55 pulse-shm-3981461026
-r-------- 1 saml saml 67108904 Jul 18 18:06 pulse-shm-799251885
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml       12 Jul 24 10:59 somefile.txt
```

However this consumes no actual diskspace, it's using RAM.